# Strip + Ubercart

Tags: stripe-payments, ubercart

I am using strip +  ubercart and its workin great on site where have HTTP

But when I trie to use on site enabled with HTTPS certificate etc I get below error:

> Payment failed for order 32: Stripe Customer Creation Failed for order
>   32: Invalid response object from API: (HTTP response code was 0)

Please suggest what I can do to resolve this, I tries searching but havent found any support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the stripe api and ran all it's unit tests. That way I could find that curl was disabled. By enabling following functions in php, all unit tests succeeded and it got working:

```
shell_exec
proc_open
curl_exec
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you are also the 'jas' at drupal.org / node / 2635338 - so I saw that after writing the reply below - so for anyone else who runs into this . . .

You do not say which Stripe library you are using - or version of stripe gateway you are using - however; I cannot imagine how it is working http  at all - so a suggestion is in https mode go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html  and https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and run the tests to make sure your SSL is working the best it can.  Stripe will throw errors like that if you are using tokenization code improperly.  There is a way to do a "dictionary" send using the old method  of a "card" parameter versus the new method of the "source" parameter - which Stripe documentation loosely says is the same but they are NOT.

Depending on which version of the module as a gateway and stripe library (assuming Drupal 7 module) you are using - one version of the drupal module does have a js error in the js file which will also fail.  You can watch what is happening using Chrome developer tools to see if js error are coming in the mix.   In Chrome it is accessed with "Ctrl-Shift-I"

The Drupal 7 module module is NOT made to work with Stripe's  checkout.js - only stripe.js

If you do not have your - again assuming again Drupal 7 - SSL set up correctly - or are using "secure pages" and it is not configured correctly it too may be the source of an error in the callback process

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is how in my case I solved http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184008/invalid-response-object-from-api-http-response-code-was-0 and started support issue on module https://www.drupal.org/node/2635338